# Micromax mmx352g 3G USB modem not working in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, internet-connection, usb-modem

Whenever I plugged in the modem to 12.10, I get an error message: (system problem).

When I look for the modem in the computer - there was an unknown device (that is the modem). So I need a driver for that modem. I am not able to connect Internet, but in 11.10 there was no problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution.

open terminal
then type 'sudo su' (without inverted comma)
enter the password
then type `echo 1C9E 9605 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id`

wait for a minute (do not close the terminal while waiting) 
and u should now see your default network

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the Micromax modem is a dialup Modem and you will need to install a driver.

I think this Ubuntu community page will answer your questions - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto

Comment: http://suriish.com/2012/10/23/how-to-connect-internet-through-usb-modem-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: http://suriish.com/2012/10/23/how-to-connect-internet-through-usb-modem-on-ubuntu-12-10/      I try that in the url but not working